# The simplest Turing-complete language

Tags: turing-completeness

To prove that a new language is Turing-complete the authors need to show that it can simulate any other (already known) Turing-complete language.

I wonder what Turing-complete language is the simplest to simulate? [Bitwise Cyclic Tag](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag) looks very easy. Are there better candidates?